# Exporting constants in files with abstract classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have been exporting constant variables from files within my Typescript files like so

```
export const VALIDATION = {
  AMOUNT_MAX_VALUE: 100_000_000,
  AMOUNT_MIN_VALUE: 0,
  DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH: 50,
};
```

These constant files would only contain this one export and no accompanying class. Recently a colleague mentioned that it would be better to export these same constants using an abstract class like so

```
export abstract class VALIDATION {
  public static readonly AMOUNT_MAX_VALUE = 100_000_000;
  public static readonly AMOUNT_MIN_VALUE = 0;
  public static readonly DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH = 50;
};
```

since it allows for developers to see the values of the constant variables within VSCode.

My gut reaction to this pattern is that it is strange to use an abstract class in this manner, and I've been unable to find any resources describing this pattern elsewhere.

Does using an abstract class to export constant values have a negative impact on the application during build or runtime?

Answer (score 0):

both of them allow to see the values. but the thing is that with the first case you can edit them

```js
export const VALIDATION = {
  AMOUNT_MAX_VALUE: 100_000_000,
  AMOUNT_MIN_VALUE: 0,
  DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH: 50,
};

VALIDATION.AMOUNT_MIN_VALUE = 5; // works
```

While within a class and readonly flags you can't.

Also you could use an enum instead.

```js
export enum VALIDATION {
    AMOUNT_MAX_VALUE = 100_000_000,
    AMOUNT_MIN_VALUE = 0,
    DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH = 50,
};
```

then you have an object instead of a class, that is a bit better performance wise.